# How to write local image file path as a uri path

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-snap-carousel

I want to convert the local image file path to the uri path so that in place of uri where a website is require i want to put the local image directory.
I am showing the code below..

```
state = {
        search: '',
        images: [
            '../../assets/assets/img/formula.png',  //***this  is not working
            'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?water',
            'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?girl',
            'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?tree'
          ]
      };


//Image is used here..

<SliderBox images={this.state.images} />
```

In image array i want the first image must include from my local file image.
Please someone tell how to do that so that in image I can include my local image file path

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Ex..:

```
import Formula from '../../assets/assets/img/formula.png';
```

Then you can use Formula as an image!
You can use `require('../../assets/assets/img/formula.png')` too.

Comment: but not working, as an array .i.e images array element is expecting the image as a uri format.

Comment: as you can the the commented part iamge object is as a local image file but there it expecting the uri path so how to convert that local image path to uri such that  i can use that there

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hopefully it can help someone. You can use `resolveAssetSource` from `Image`, so going back to your code it would look like this,

```
state = {
    search: '',
    images: [
        Image.resolveAssetSource(require("../../assets/assets/img/formula.png")).uri,
        'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?water',
        'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?girl',
        'https://source.unsplash.com/1024x768/?tree'
      ]
  };
```

Of course you would need to import `Image` first,

```
import { Image } from "react-native";
```